# Why is the coefficient of kinetic friction greater than the coefficient of static friction?

Tags: friction

I am a physics major taking freshman year physics courses. We did a lab experiment where we were given three objects and inclined plane, and we were asked to find the coefficients of kinetic and static friction for each object. The coefficient we found for static friction was greater than kinetic friction in each object. It was greater by about 0.05 in each object (e.g. mu_s = .22, mu_k = .29).

Our method to find the coefficient of kinetic friction was to measure the acceleration down the ramp using a vernier sensor, then solve using the mass and the angle, which was arbitrarily chosen to be 26.8 degrees.

Our method to find the coefficient static friction is not very precise. We used a pulley system to elevate the ramp until the object was just barely sliding, and we measured the incline at that point. Therefore, our coefficient of static friction is really only a best estimate.

As the saying goes, "it's a poor workman who blames his tools,"  or in this case his experimental method. But there is no special condition to make this situation predictable, and I can't find another explanation other than our "best estimate" method simply isn't accurate enough. Or is the 0.05 a negligible amount?

Any ideas?

The current draft of my lab report is posted here.

Comment: If you didn't characterize the precision of your methods, then you can't even say that they are not precise enough. The phrase "is not very precise" is not a replacement for carefully designed control experiments and calibration. From an experimental point of view I would simply say that you have to try harder when you re-do the measurement.

Comment: Without a quantification of your errors and an exact description of what you did I don't see how we can meaningfully answer this.

Comment: I have added my formal lab report to this post, if that would help. It has all of my measurements and calculations. Note my current thoughts on this problem in the discussions section.

Comment: If I wanted to repeat your experiment, your report does not contain enough detail to make that possible. In particular the dimensions and materials of ramp and blocks, surface cleansing? How measurements were made - "vernier devices" is unhelpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the coefficient of static friction be less than that of kinetic friction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541/)

Comment: Are you asking why you find the static friction to be greater than the dynamic friction? If so see the question I've linked.

Comment: Hi Zack Hutchens. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Comment: What's the problem?  The last I heard, in sliding friction, static is always greater than kinetic.